# Create Firestore document only the first time a user signs in with google oAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to react and firebase and was trying to create a firestore document only during the creation of user.

Its working fine on the local provider as there sign in and sign up are two different things but when it comes to google o Auth both the options use same function.

So how do i create my initial documnet during creation of user via google o Auth as it just resets my entire document when i log out and log in back.

**googleAuth function**

```
    function googleAuth(provider) {

        return firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(async function createUserDb(userCredentials) {
                await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userCredentials.user.uid), {myList: []},{ merge: true })
                })
    }
```

**sign up and sign in functions**

```
    function signUp(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
            async function createUserDb(userCredentials) {
                console.log(userCredentials.user.uid);
                await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userCredentials.user.uid), {myList: []})
    })
    }

    function signIn(email, password) {
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
```

**my firestore users collection when a new user is created (google auth user here)**

[image: firestore user collection]

**it should save the data even after sign in (local auth user here)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after scraping through some posts found **.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser** method which checks if the user has created new account or is already a user which fixed my issue.

Thank you for any help that you guys provided.

```
    function googleAuth(provider) {

        return firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(async function createUserDb(userCredentials) {
                if(userCredentials.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userCredentials.user.uid), {myList: []},{ merge: true })
                } 
                })
    }
```